# Installing private GitHub repositories on DataBricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks, ssh-keys, python-wheel

I'm running Python `wheels` on Azure Databricks job. One of the `wheel` imports private repository from GitHub. Installation of `wheel` on Databricks cluster fails, as there is no SSH on Databricks.

What is the most elegant way of providing Databricks environment with SSH private Key?

Answer (score 1):

Here the sample procedure of installation of Git repo on databricks.

Use a tool like `pip` to install wheels. Leave it to the tool to discover and download the file if this is for a project hosted on PyPI.

```py
pip install wheel
```

You can then tell  `pip`  to install the project (and it'll download the wheel if available), or the wheel file directly:

```py
pip install project_name  # discover, download and install
pip install wheel_file.whl  # directly install the wheel
```

The  `wheel`  module, once installed, also is runnable from the command line, you can use this to install already-downloaded wheels:

```py
python -m wheel install wheel_file.whl
```

Also see https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

The way of providing Databricks environment with SSH private Key.

SSH into the Spark driver:

Open the cluster configuration page.

Click Advanced Options.

Click the SSH tab.

Note the Driver Hostname.

Open a local terminal.

Run the following command, replacing the hostname and private key file path:

```
ssh ubuntu@<hostname> -p 2200 -i <private-key-file-path>
```

Please refer the document on SSH: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/clusters/azure-ssh-cluster-driver-node